# Refresh entity framework view result

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, view, orm

I have in database a view named `vue_demande` and I need to get all its rows in my application :

```
public IEnumerable<vue_demande> GetAllDemandes()
    {
        if ( context == null) context = GetContext();
        return context.Set<vue_demande>().AsNoTracking <vue_demande>().ToList();
    }
```

When I modify some values of tables of the view, it isn't refreshed!!!

I need to know :

1. Why this happens?
2. How can I Get the list of rows of view up to date?

Comment: As a general rule, unless you need it otherwise, you should always create a new context for every request. Unless you need transactions or can group up the requests in a logical way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are modifying values outside of your context.  A `context` will only ask the database for information that it doesn't already have.  If you ask a context to get the same information again it'll just use the values it retrieved last time (this saves trips to the server).

To "refresh" just get a new context:

```
context = GetContext(); //Assuming your GetContext method returns a new context
```